# Error al ejecutar json

Tags: php, json

Tengo una aplicación que se conectará a una API externa. En el manual de la API, json se ve así:

```
{
  "from": "5510999999999",
  "to": "55108888888888",
  "contents": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Hi Zenvia!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Mi PHP se ve así:

```
class zenvia{
      
    public function SMS($telefone,$mensagem)
    {
        $method = 'POST';
        $from = '55219999999999';
        $to = '55'.$telefone;
        $msg = $mensagem;
       $body = [
            "from" => $from,
            "to" => $to,
            "contents" => [
                            "type" => "text",
                            "text" => $msg
                          ]          
       ];
        $campos = json_encode($body);
         $url = 'https://api.zenvia.com/v2/channels/sms/messages';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $campos);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                'Content-Type: application/json',
                                                'X-API-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                                            ));
        $resposta = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $resposta;
        if(curl_error($ch))
        {
            echo curl_error($ch);
            return curl_error($ch);
        }
        else
        {
            json_decode($resposta);
            
        }
  curl_close($ch);  
    }

}
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación, devuelve el siguiente error:

> {"code":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Request has one or more errors\n
> In body\n For Content-Type application/json\n Unable to deserialize
> value\n at: allOf\n at: 0 > contents\n Expected an array. Received:
> [object Object]\n at: 1 > contents\n Expected an array. Received:
> undefined"}

No tengo mucha experiencia con PHP / Json. ¿Cómo puedo corregir eso?

Perdón por mi español.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error dice exactamente cual es el problema:

> *"contents Expected an array. Received: [object Object]"*

#### Solución:

Necesitas que `contents` sea un arreglo con un objeto dentro (*en `PHP` un arreglo asociativo*):

```
$body = [
    "from" => $from,
    "to" => $to,
    "contents" => [ // El arreglo
        ["type" => "text", "text" => $msg], // Luego los datos
    ]
];
```

---

Referencias:

- [Send a SMS message - ZenAPI](https://zenvia.github.io/zenvia-openapi-spec/v2/#tag/SMS/paths/%7E1channels%7E1sms%7E1messages/post)

Comment: Funcionó. Muchas gracias Marcos.